# Unhashable type: 'list' error in values in dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, defaultdict

I have two new dictionaries as follows:

```
a = {Banana: 60, Apple: 90, Pear: 80}
b = {60: 25, 90: 45, 89: 94}
```

I wanted to create a new dictionary that only took the value in dictionary b and then merged it into a. So like Banana has a value of 60, which is also the key in b. The value of 60 is 25. So in the end I want `Banana: 25`

So I wrote this code as follows:
`{k:b[v] for k,v in a.items() if v in b}`

But I keep getting the following error: `unhashable type: 'list'` I understand that it might be because my values for `b[v]` are like `[[25], [45], [94]]`

I tried converting it into a tuple in my dict comprehension, tried flattening it but still no luck.

Any help would be great

Comment: it is not that in b values are lists, it is that in a values are lists, hence you try to access a dict through a list which cannot be hashable.

Comment: That is weird, you should be getting `NameError: name 'Banana' is not defined`.

Comment: I didn't reproduce your error, maybe it is version problem

Comment: You asked basically the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55565690/unhashable-type-list-in-dictionary) ~6 hours before this one. Why did you create another instance of that question? Also, your real dicts seem to have a different structure from what you show here, or what does *my values for `b[v]` are like `[[25], [45], [94]]`* mean? Please provide data that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
a = {'Banana': 60, 'Apple': 90, 'Pear': 80}
b = {60: 25, 90: 45, 89: 94}
c = {k:(b[a[k]] if a[k] in b else a[k]) for k in a}
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
c = {'Banana': 25, 'Apple': 45, 'Pear': 80}
```

Comment: @EdwonWersersoin Check with the updated one, shouldn't get any error in python 3+.